# running ride.py to launch RIDE opening code in IE

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to launch RIDE for the firsttime due to some problem i could not launch RIDE.
I installed python version 2.7.6, wxPython2.8 unicode version,robot framework ride-1.5.2.1. On giving D:\robot fm sw  in the commandprompt i am got "Robot Framework 2.8.3 ".

But now on running ride.py RIDE is not opening but instead some code is opening in IE.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jyothi

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your Python installation. Files with .py extension should be executed by Python, not opened in other application (IE in your case).
If possible, you should, with Administrator rights:

1. Install a newer version of Python with the same architecture as Windows (i.e., 64bit or 32bit). The most recent version is 2.7.11.
2. Install wxPython2.8 unicode the with the same architecture as Python.
3. Optionally, install robotframework newest version (3.0) with pip:

pip install -U robotframework

4. Install robotframework-ride with pip:

pip install -U robotframework-ride

See the installation instructions at [RIDE Wiki](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Installing new version of python helped me.